# Translation from Maple to C++

Tags: c++, maple

Hey, 
So I have a maple program which does bisection method and I have to convert it to C++. I tried converting it according to what the code generation help on the maple forums said but it kept throwing out errors. I would appreciate some help in this.
Thanks,

Here is the code for maple

---

Use the bisection method to solve the following mathematical problem: 
a. smallest positive root of equation

```
f(x):=evalf(1/x-evalf(Pi)*cos(evalf(Pi)*x));
```

with delta = 10^-5 and eps = 10^-6

```
plot(f(x),x=.05..10.0);
```

From graph above we can conclude that given equation has smallest positive real root located between 0.0 and 2.0

To get their values with accuracy required we invoke bisection method with root isolation interval (0.01,2.0):

```
Bisect:=proc(funct_equation,ai,bi,Mi,epsfi,deltaxi) local k,M,a,b,u,v,w,c,e,epsf,deltax,feq, notsolved: M:=Mi: feq:=funct_equation: a:=ai: b:=bi: epsf:=epsfi: deltax:=deltaxi: notsolved:=true: u:=evalf(subs(x=a,feq)): v:=evalf(subs(x=b,feq)): printf("a=%+9.6f   %+12.6e\nb=%+9.6f   %+12.6e\n\n",a,u,b,v); e:=b-a; if (sign(u)<>sign(v)) then   printf(" n       x            f\n");   for k from 1 by 1 while (k<M and notsolved) do:
    e:=0.5*e;
    c:=a+e;
    w:=evalf(subs(x=c,feq)):
    printf("%2d  %+9.6f    %+12.6e\n",k,c,w);
    if (abs(e)<deltax or abs(w)<epsf) then
      notsolved:=false:
    else
      if (sign(w) <> sign(u)) then
        b:=c: v:=w:
      else
        a:=c: u:=w:
      fi:
    fi:    od:    printf("Root = %+9.6f  function = %+12.6e\n",0.5*(a+b),evalf(subs(x=0.5*(a+b),feq))); fi: end: with(plots):
```

Warning, the name change coords has been redefined

```
Bisect(f(x),0.01,2.0,30,1.0e-6,1.0e-5):
```

Comment: You might want to post the 'converted to C++' code and the errors.  People may find it easier to help.

Comment: The line `evalf(subs(x=c,feq))` where `feq` is a function object makes this look particularly non-trivial.

Comment: ok so according to the code generation forums on maple 
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=CodeGeneration

The only error I get is premature input and the call that I make to convert it for example C(function)

Comment: So basically its not even converting anything to C

Answer (score 1):

You won't need that `subs` call, if you keep your `feq` as a procedure.

```
restart:
Bisect:=proc(func::procedure,ai,bi,Mi,epsfi,deltaxi)
local k::integer,
  M::integer,
  a,b,u,v,
  w::float,
  c,e,
  epsf::float,
  deltax,
  notsolved;
  M:=Mi:
  a:=ai: b:=bi: epsf:=epsfi:
  deltax:=deltaxi: notsolved:=true:
  u:=func(a);
  v:=func(b);
  printf("a=%+9.6f   %+12.6e\nb=%+9.6f   %+12.6e\n\n",a,u,b,v);
  e:=b-a;
  if (sign(u)<>sign(v)) then
    printf(" n       x            f\n");
    for k from 1 by 1 while (k<M and notsolved) do
      e:=0.5*e;
      c:=a+e;
      w:=func(c);
      printf("%2d  %+9.6f    %+12.6e\n",k,c,w);
      if (abs(e)<deltax or abs(w)<epsf) then
        notsolved:=false:
      else
       if (sign(w) <> sign(u)) then
         b:=c: v:=w:
       else
         a:=c: u:=w:
       fi:
     fi:
   od:
   printf("Root = %+9.6f  function = %+12.6e\n",0.5*(a+b),func(0.5*(a+b),feq));
 fi:
 0.5*(a+b);
end:

with(plots):

f:=subs(Pi=evalf[16](Pi),proc(x::float) 1/x-Pi*cos(Pi*x); end proc);

Bisect(f,0.01,2.0,30,1.0e-6,1.0e-5);

f(%);

CodeGeneration[C](f);

CodeGeneration[C](Bisect);
```

Also, if you start with an expression for `f`, you can always turn it into an operator (a sort of procedure, but which too can be code-generated) using the `unapply` command.

For example, I could also have created the procedure `f` in the following ways. (Note that one of these produces a default 10-digits approximation to Pi in the generated C code, and the other a 16-digit approximation.)

```
f_expression := 1/x-Pi*cos(Pi*x);

f:=unapply(f_expression, [x::float]);

CodeGeneration[C](f);

f:=subs(Pi=evalf[16](Pi),unapply(f_expression, [x::float]));

CodeGeneration[C](f);
```